# Having trouble passing react props value to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am having trouble passing a prop to another component 
This code is from my App Component it is triggered by onClick

```
 addServer() {
    let serverArr = ['Server 1','Server 2'];
    serverArr.push(this.state.serverName);
    return (
        <ServerList server={serverArr}/> // Here i am passing the array as prop
      )

  }
```

here is a code from the component i want to use the prop, i am trying to display the passed in props

```
export class ServerList extends React.Component {
    render(){
        let server = this.props.server.map((item, index) => {
           return <li key={index}> {item} </li>;
        })
        return (
                <div className="container-server">
                <ul> {server} </ul>
                </div>
        )
   }
}
```

Comment: Is the data `serverArr` received asynchronously, because there isn't any error in mapping

Comment: What's the problem exactly?  Is there an error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your case but my guess is , since you are mutating the array by using

```
array.push()
```

you should call

```
 this.forceUpdate()
```

function for re-render the component so just try this

```
addServer() {
let serverArr = ['Server 1','Server 2'];
serverArr.push(this.state.serverName);
this.forceUpdate();
return (
    <ServerList server={serverArr}/> // Here i am passing the array as prop
  )  }
```

Answer (score -1):

What is the value of `this.state.serverName` on the `serverArr.push` line? Console.log `this.state.serverName` before that line.

Also console.log `serverArr` after `serverArr.push` line.

Then console.log `server` after `let server` line.

You should also console.log `this.props.server` before `let sever` line.

Making these checks you should pinpoint where the error is.

Finally, what is the actual error. Is something written in the console, or you don't see the component, or component is rendered strangely?

EDIT:
You should have `serverArr` in `state` in `AppComponent`, and then render it. For example:

```
class AppComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.state = {serverArr: ['Server 1', 'Server2']};
         this.addServer = this.addServer.bind(this);
    }

    function addServer() {
    }

    render(){
        return (
              <div>
                <ServerList server={serverArr}/>
                <button onClick={this.addServer}>Add</button>
              </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: No error the mapping just not displaying, also i already console.log them they have the expected value...

Comment: Change  <ServerList server={serverArr}/> with simple text "ABC" to see if this is rendered. Also remove className="container-server" to see if it is hiding.

Comment: it is not rendering

Comment: If "ABC" is not rendering then it is not problem in passing props but in in how addServer is called, and the code around this. You should make a new question with the calling (wrapping) code, or edit the existing question with that info.

Comment: addServer method is not inside render is that okay?